# Change Default Wordpress MU Blog

Tags: multisite

I have a wordpress multisite installation and a default blog under `/` (let's call this blogZ). I want to create e new blog called blogX and set it as the default one.

The blogZ should appear under `/soccer` path.

This is what i tried to do:

1. clone default blog: impossible, there isn't any option for the default blog.
2. change default blog in `wp-config.php`, working on `define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 26);` and also doing a try changing `define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);`. NO RESULTS

How could we solve the problem?